# Determining size in MBs and user count for 'one particular' site collection

Tags: powershell, site, size

I need to determe the size of a site collection in MB.
I tried:

```
Get-SPSiteAdministration | select Url, DiskUsed, UsersCount
```

But it returns DiskUsed and UserCount for all the site collections in the WebApp. Replacing 'select Url' by URL of a Site Collection returns an error!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line will return the size of all the site collection in MB:

```
Get-SPSite | select url, @{label="Size in MB";Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property "Size in MB" | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

If you want the size of a specific site collection add the url after the Get-SPSite command:

```
Get-SPSite http://mySite/sites/mySitecollection | select url, @{label="Size in MB";Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property "Size` in MB" | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped